# Access to an object based on function parameter

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to access to an object based on a parameter on this function?

```
function fnc (num) {
  const obj1 = { whatever : "foo1"}
  const obj2 = { whatever : "foo2"}
  return console.log([`obj${num}`].whatever)
}
```

fnc(1)
// Expected Result foo1 but got undefined

Also tried with same result

```
`obj${num}`.whatever
```

Any idea? Thank you!!

Comment: This looks like a job for an *array* rather than numbered variables, no?

Comment: Some languages allow that sort of thing. JavaScript isn't one of them. Use an array.

Comment: Trying to acces to const idRef = useRef(null); but I have multiple of them (const addressRef = useRef(null); ...) and I need to somehow have a parameter in the function and add to it the "Ref" in order to be able to access

Comment: not going to happen. Use an object/set with keys or an array.

Comment: `const myRefs = useRef({});`